# jquery validate phone number and extension

Tags: jquery, validation

I haven't seen a good RegEx using jQuery validate plugin that validates a phone number and extension. Does anyone have a good solution for this? The required format can be shown to the user: ie

`Example: (555) 555-1234 x 1234`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// custom extension regex
phone: function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})\s*-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}(\s*x\s*\d{4})?$/.test(value);
},
```

Answer (score 4):

You can look in the [additional-methods.js](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/additional-methods.js) file, there's a few choices in there.  None of them support extension though, so you'd have to modify one to match what you want (the extension part as @jahroy suggested).  Here's a similar one:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})\s*-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}(\s*x\s*\d{4})?$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

You'll have to decide for yourself whether to allow the extension to be optional or not (I left it optional).

Comment: awesome dude, works great. check my answer for how I implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your post, you could use a regex similar to this:

```
([0-9]{3}) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4} x [0-9]{4}
```

That may not be exactly correct... You may have to use some escape characters, but that should be the basic idea.

More reading [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).